# How to alias in Laravel Eager Loading Array without changing method name

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I need to alias when I do a Laravel eager loading:

```
$employee = Employee::with(['profilepic', 'emp_company'])->find($user->employee_id);
```

In my model I have profilepic function and emp_company function. I need to pass a company object without renaming the emp_company funtion to company.

I need to to this because I want the JSON response as profilepic and company. for the frontend I need emp_company object as company. It is possible to alias.

Answer (score 0):

Name your JSON as `"company"` inside the array.

Try this:

```
$employee = Employee::with(['profilepic' => 'profilepic', 'company' => 'emp_company'])->find($user->employee_id);
```

Comment: not worked this, geting 500 server error

Comment: Also give "profilepic" an index as updated above.